# Provided host localhost could NOT be bound. Please provide a different host address or hostname

Tags: angular, macos, terminal, angular-cli, macos-high-sierra

suddenly i start getting following error on "ng serve" command.

```
Provided host localhost could NOT be bound. Please provide a different host address or hostname
```

not sure what triggered this error. using --host 0.0.0.0 works but i'm using auth0 for login authentication which doesn't allow 0.0.0.0. i searched for solution but couldn't find any that point's to the cause or that solves it for localhost. Anybody have idea how to fix this?
Thank you!

i'm using node 9.10.1, angular-cli 1.7.4, OS: darwin x64

Comment: What research have you done? This is a very common error and lots of history that has to do with maintenance and version details you do not share here.

Comment: @jdv i searched all i can. found few but it points to use --host 0.0.0.0 instead of solving for localhost(127.0.0.0). i'm using node 9.10.1, angular-cli 1.7.4, OS: darwin x64

Comment: Yes, but you never told us what you did so far, and what your findings were. This wastes time getting past all the "I tried that already" stuff. Have you really followed all the possible solutions on just the  github bug reports? Why don't these apply? What makes your case different. Let's get to the important stuff sooner.

Comment: @jdv, as i said i found few but those suggest to use --host 0.0.0.0 instead of solving for localhost. i checked /etc/hosts etc too 127.0.0.1 localhost is also listed there. but still i keep getting same error.

Comment: @jdv one more thing, it was working few hours ago, i think i got this problem after i installed smbup. i removed smbup but the error didn;t go away

Comment: Ah ha! This is the sort of detail that you need to share early. Something changed when you did something. You need to work from there, and it is key that you tell us the whole story.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

not sure what caused it. but running `sudo route -n flush` and restarting computer fixed it for me.